# XCode run all the tests (even the disabled ones)

Tags: xcode, testing

I have XCode 6.1.1 and I'm using KIF to do some automated testing.

As you can see in the image I have almost all the test disabled but when I run test it runs some tests randomly (even the disabled ones), sometimes it runs all the tests, sometimes just the selected, it's really weird.

Even if I clic the desired test and clic "Test ..." it run other tests (even the disabled ones)

[image]

Any fix? 
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're not using Specta by any chance are you?

Comment: no, I'm just using kif why?

Comment: We saw similar behaviors with Specta and how it hooked up to register the tests. Have not seen this with just KIF though, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Possible workaround: disable all of them and then re-select only the ones you want. Seems to be enough. cheers